# Can we show $\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}e^{-\lambda_n}<\infty$ if $\lambda_n\to\infty$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, exponential-function

If $(\lambda_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq(0,\infty)$ in nondecreasing with $\lambda_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\infty$, how can we show that $\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}e^{-\lambda_n}<\infty$?

It clearly holds $1>e^{-\lambda_n}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$. And $\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}e^{-\lambda_n}\le\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\frac1{\lambda_n^2}$. Maybe it's easier to show that the right-hand side is finite.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  Let $\lambda_n= \ln n$.  Then your sum is the harmonic series.